# react navigation tab navigator inside static layout

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Can I achieve this layout?

sketch of layout:

[image]

the header part is shared across all tabs. it's part of the layout in this screen.
and each tab contains a scrollView.

btw, I have tried defining the tab navigator as a component and using that inside the render method, along with the static header component.

```
render() {
  return ( 
    <StaticHeaderComponent />
    <MyTabNavigator />
  ) 
}
```

that does not work. the tab navigator does not render at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple working example:

*MyTabNavigator.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

class FirstTab extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <Text>first tab</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

class SecondTab extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <Text>second tab</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

const MyNavigator = TabNavigator({
    first: { screen: FirstTab },
    second: { screen: SecondTab }
},
{
    tabBarPosition: 'top'
})

export default MyNavigator
```

*App.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import MyTabNavigator from './MyTabNavigator'

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <View // place your StaticHeaderComponent here
                    style={{height: 100, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
                />
                <MyTabNavigator/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: As per react navigation 3, this gives the error : Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly.`

Answer (score 0):

For react-navigation 3.+ the ***Common mistakes*** section of the documentation comes in handy. You can find the documentation and the example [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator).

Specifically, you need to expose the `static router` and pass `navigation` as a prop. You can further customise the tab styles as required.

```
const TabbyNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({   
  Tab: TabScreen,   
  AnotherTab: AnotherTabScreen
});

class SomeScreen extends React.Component {   
  static router = TabbyNavigator.router;

  render() {
    return (
      <TabbyNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    );   
  } 
}
```